# A tool to measure overhead of establishing TCP connections

Tags: svn, http, tcp, debugging, keepalive

I need a tool which would while doing port forwarding measure how much time was spent establishing TCP connections vs total time passed. Charles debugging proxy has the port forwarding feature and shows the total time from the beginning of the first to the end of the last connection in a selected group but it doesn't show the connection establishment overhead.

We're using a remote SVN server and it is not configured to use Keep-Alive but we do not have direct access to the server so we need a proof of this causing an overhead and slowing things down to convince the other party to change the configuration.

Comment: What is wrong with using Wireshark, and examining the time when you sent a TCP SYN to the time that you sent your first TCP data segment?  That said, you seem to be making the assumption that the server configuration is the problem and not: A) end-to-end latency, B) packet loss, or C) load on the server's disk/cpu

Comment: After 20 years of debugging problems like this, my first approach is to look for significant packet loss (> 0.5% of the packets sent).  You typically would do this with [`winmtr`](http://winmtr.net/) (windows) or [`mtr`](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) (*nix).  If you can't nail down any significant packet loss, then consider server load and latency issues.  Sniffing is certainly helpful after you have eliminated other sources of TCP delay.

Comment: I could use Wireshark but this may be difficult with getting permission to use it as our corporate policy prohibits sniffers. Also I'm not very comfortable with Wireshark and a higher level tool would be more convenient. As to the cause I may be wrong of course.

Comment: Have you resolved the original problem?  If so, was it the lack of keep-alive?